# How can I make a separate boot partition in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, uefi

I've got an old computer running Windows 7.  Windows is installed in BIOS-MBR mode.  In the course of trying to dual boot Linux on it, I found that Windows 7 is stored on one partition, with the boot manager contained on the C: drive at

```
C:\boot
```

I'd really like to move the boot manager to its own partition, but I'm not completely sure how to do this without messing up my system and how to tell Windows to boot from the new partition.

**What I've managed to do:**  I've shrunk the Windows partition and created a new 512MB FAT32 partition, which I want to put the boot directory on to.  I thought about marking this new partition as active, but when I tried to, I got a message warning me that I should only mark a partition as active if it contains a full operating system.  This partition will never contain a full OS, just the boot manager.

How do I get my new partition to boot Windows?

Comment: `C:\boot` is not that EFI directory, EFI must be on its own FAT32 partition, what makes you think you are not using MBR instead of GPT?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have checked, and I am indeed using MBR.  I know the computer is capable of booTING IN UEfi mode, though.

Comment: It might be capable but you would have to install both Windows and Mint again to do that.  So you don't have an EFI partition if you are using MBR.

Comment: @Ramhound - OK, so Windows is booted in BIOS-MBR mode.  I'll edit my question accordingly.  So I eventually want to install Linux in BIOS-MBR mode as well.  But it should still be possible to move the bootloader to its own partition, right?

Comment: What makes you think that isn't the case?  Based on you earlier confusion perhaps you should help us verify that is indeed the case?  Based on what you claim is in the contents of `C:\boot` makes me think your mistake about your conclusion.

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying.  What are you asking me to help verify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31756/discussion-between-donkey-2009-and-ramhound).